# Getting strange error when adding sublayout in Visual Studio 2013 using Sitecore Rocks

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.5, sitecore-rocks

When trying to add a new sublayout using Visual Studio 2013 and Sitecore Rocks I am getting a strange error.  Here is what I did:

- Right click on folder where I want to add new sublayout
- Select Add | New Item...
- In the add new item dialog select Visual C# | Sitecore | Renderings
- Then select Sublayout
- Enter the name of the new sublayout

Then I see the following error message:

[image]

The result is that Visual Studio adds a new ASCX file, but it does not add the code behind and it also does not do the usual thing where it opens up Sitecore Rocks and asks me where I would like to add the new sublayout.  So something is definitely not working correctly.  This had all been working fine for months.  And all of a sudden it is no longer working.  I can't figure it out.  I also can't figure out exactly what that error message is referring to.  When I look at the project file there is seemingly nothing wrong with the project file.  The project loads fine.  I can't figure this out at all.